# How to use embedded signing with witness using templates in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign_esign python SDK package for docusign.
How to properly create embedded signing with witness while using docusign templates?

I am able to do embedded signing from template but i can't figure out how to handle witnesses.

The witness is added in template, it has signing tab in it.
I used TemplateRole to add witness, tried without adding it to TemplateRoles. Nothing seems to work.

The embedded envelope is created, i can sign it, but user is not prompted to specify witness.

Comment: can you do that from the web app first? if you can't do that - you can't do it from the API either. You may need to create a new developer account if you don't have this feature

Answer (score 0):

I work in DocuSign developer support. There was a known issue EC-2764 "Witness not working in composite template API call." The fix is available on demo now.

In order to get the witness you define in your API call you have to use the exact rolename that is saved on the template. On my template that is
"roleName": "Witness 65580212 for 70485785",

So the working API call JSON body looks like this:

```
  "emailSubject": "witness template",
  "emailBlurb": "",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "8a951504-29bb-4592-be7c-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Geoff Test",
                "email": "gxxxxx@gmail.com",
                "signWithWitness": "true",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Employee",

              }
            ],
            "witnesses": [
              {
                "witnessFor": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Witness 65580212 for 70485785",
                "name": "Jane",
                "email": "jxxxx@gmail.com",
                "deliveryMethod": "email",
                "note": "Please Witness the signature",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "status": "created",
                "defaultRecipient": "false",
                "recipientType": "witness"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That API call pre-fills the witness information, but the signer can choose who they want for the witness, so they can edit.